# How to get video file length uploaded to Amazon S3?

Tags: php, video, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I am using plupload to upload video files to Amazon S3 and am playing it using JWPlayer. Before video file is played, I display list of video files uploaded to S3. In this list I would like to display the duration of the video.

I have read the ffmpeg approach used with PHP. Is there a better approach to get the duration?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Use `ffprobe` to get the duration. Some cli examples you can adapt:

### show duration in seconds

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 input.mp4
108.501000
```

### show duration in sexagesimal format (`HH:MM:SS.MICROSECONDS`)

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -sexagesimal -of default=nw=1:nk=1 input.mp4
0:01:48.501000
```

Comment: That works thanks. I still wish they have something simpler to get it. This is a highly reusable piece of information for video processing.

Comment: @ArnaudLeyder I made a simpler command omitting `eval`, `grep`, and `echo`.

Comment: Oh that looks nicer. +1